# Continuous function with constant

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

There is function $f(x)=e^{(c^2 - 1)/x^2}$ when $x \neq 0$ and $f(x)=c$ when $x=0$.
Why is this function continuous (the $c$ is a constant)? 
I know that for the function to be continuous, $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)$
but I'm not sure where to start

Comment: Surely you have other results on continuous functions, like "The composition of two continuous functions is continuous" and "the product of two continuous functions is contunious".

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for the format edit help. I'm not following what you are saying. As x approaches infinity, the limit is 1, but how do I prove it's continuous?

Comment: Continuous **where**? At what points? Clearly it's continuous at $c$, and at any $a != 0$. But what about $a = 0$? Is it true that $lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = f(0)$? That is: does $lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = c$?

Comment: PS As a function defined on real numbers, not "extended reals", the behavior of $f$ as $x\to+\infty$ has no bearing on the continuity of $f$ *on its domain* (and vice versa), as its domain contains no such thing as $+\infty$.

Comment: @BrianO I think I'm getting it, but for which values of c is the function continuous? How do I approach that?

Comment: That is possible only when c=+1, in this case  c^2 - 1 = 0 and (c^2 - 1)/x = 0 for any value of x including x=0. Hence f(x) = e^0 = 1 which is cotiniously constant from  x→+∞ and x→-∞ as well as x = 0.

Comment: That is possible only when c=+1, in this case  c^2 - 1 = 0 so (c^2 - 1)/x = 0 for any value of x including x=0. Hence f(x) = e^0 = 1 which is continuously constant from  x→+∞ and x→-∞ as well as for x = 0. Hence only for c=1 the function will be continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

note that, for $c^2-1=a$ we have:
$$
\lim _{x \to 0}\;e^{\frac{a}{x^2}}= \begin {cases}
=0 \quad \mbox{for} \quad a<0\\
=+\infty\quad \mbox{for} \quad a>0
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$f\; $is continuous at $x=0 \implies \lim_{x\to 0}f(x) $ exists $\implies -1\leq c\leq 1$.

$f$ is continuous at $\mathbb R$ if $c=0\;$ or $\;c=1$.

Comment: Is this correct? With $c^2 -1<0$ and $c^2 -1>0$ it is deduced that $-1<c<1$

Comment: @marble My answer is correct.$c^2-1<0\iff -1<c<1$